# How can I create a new post in Vbulletin forum from WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, webapi, vbulletin

I have a WordPress blog and also a VBulletin forum in a subdomain. I want to add a new feature to my WordPress blog in order to give the ability to visitors to ask their questions directly from the blog, without going into the forum.

Is there any web API in the VBulletin to create a new thread? Or any plugin for WordPress to create a VBulletin post from WordPress?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can post your blog posts from wordpress   via the built-in RSS poster in your vBulletin admin cp